# .htaccess in subdirectory 'overriding' parent htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, password-protection

been searching for 2 days and can't quite get the right solution due to my lack of understanding of mod_rewrite and time constraints on this project so hoping someone can help.

**The aim**

To rewrite all requests to the root index.php if the client doesn't have the correct cookie.
If the client has the correct cookie allow them to browse as they wish.

**The problem**

The htaccess in my subdirectory is taking precendence over my root htaccess, so requests such as www.mydomain.com/subdir/index.php arn't getting redirected.

**My root .htaccess**

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*pass.*$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?url=$0 [NC]
```

**My subdir htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

**Additional info**

Ideally I'm trying to create a password protected area, so all requests are routed to index.php where a password can be entered and when verified a cookie is created, allowing free browsing of contents and sub directories. So if there is a better way to accomplish this then please let me know, and I havn't gone for .htpasswd since I need custom login, error and splash pages.

Also, the subdir .htaccess is an ExpressionEngine URL handler.

Thanks.

Comment: Regardless of how you fix this, checking for the presence of a cookie is NOT good security. It's trivial to fake one, and since you're not validating the data in the cookie, just checking for its presence), your "security" system is trivial to bypass.

Comment: @Abe just a suggestion but have you thought about implementing HTTP authentication, if your only looking to allow access to directorys: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To allow execution of rewrite rules from parent .htaccess (htaccess from parent folder), you need to explicitly allow it (Apache will treat rewrite rules in current .htaccess as the only one that need to be executed, as long as rewritten URL remains in the same subfolder).

You need to add this line to your .htaccess in sub-folder:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

Apache manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

Comment: You could also put `RewriteOptions InheritDown` in parent htaccess if you want all child htaccess to inherit them.