# The .htaccess code shoud not affect my forum?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website and let's call it example.com.
I also use a htaccess which is long and I am posting a part of it

```
<filesMatch "\.(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7257600"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(js|css|pdf|txt)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600"
</filesMatch>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
```

How can I make the htaccess which is uploaded in example.com/.htaccess not affect my `forum` which is located in `example.com/forum`

I am asking for any code like this

```
<ifdirectory !"/forum">

//the htaccess code here

</ifdirectrory>
```

Comment: You would need to either place your forum in a subdomain, or maybe upload another .htaccess file in the forum subfolder.

Comment: yes, but the .htaccess code in root is forcing the /forum/ directory to do the same the htaccess for the root does (even that the /forum/ has another blank htaccess)

Comment: Does `filesMatch` work inside `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow execution of rewrite rules from parent .htaccess (htaccess from parent folder), you need to explicitly allow it (Apache will treat rewrite rules in current .htaccess as the only one that need to be executed, as long as rewritten URL remains in the same subfolder).

You need to add this line to your .htaccess in sub-folder:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

Apache manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

This is a copy of a post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337431/htaccess-in-subdirectory-overriding-parent-htaccess), no credit to me. Look to your right, in the sidebar, there are plenty of similar topics :)

Comment: Yea, but I could not find the similar questions before I decided to ask.

Comment: I understand, no problem, I was just saying. Which property exactly is the one you don't want to apply to your forum? Is it the cache-control or what?

Comment: No, the cache control is not. It is another (more important code). The code uploaded here is just an example

Comment: OK, then please be more precise (edit your initial post) because I'm afraid I can't help you further unless you show your actual problem :)