# htaccess remove existing rewrite conditions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

I've tried changing the functionality of a few rewrite conditions, but there's too many across the site I'm working on. For this one folder I'm in, I need unique funtionality, and I need to remove all existing rewrite conditions and make new ones. I've tried having just

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./item_processor.php
```

in the folder's htaccess, but other rewrite rules up the heirarchy seem to want to still cause redirects to our existing error pages when directed at a file that "doesn't exist" that I want managed by the item_processor.

How can I turn off pre-existing rewrite rules and have the ones in my current htaccess be the only ones to apply to the current folder?

Comment: When you say "up the hierarchy" are you referring to an htaccess in a different directorY?

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337431/htaccess-in-subdirectory-overriding-parent-htaccess   Or, do you still need those other htaccess files?  You could probably write a script that searches your website and renames all .htaccess files to htaccess.txt.

Comment: I need the existing htaccess files, they do a lot of important stuff across the site, I just don't need them affecting this one folder I'm working in.

Comment: Did you read the link?  It says if you put `RewriteOptions inherit` in child htaccess it will try to read the .htaccess in parent directories.

Comment: I'm specifically *not* wanting it to inherit the .htaccess of the parent directories though. Is there a "don't inherit" option?

Comment: By default the htaccess in child directories override the htaccess in parent directories.  Adding that line of code to child directory htaccess should cause it to defer to the parent directory htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet in a sub-folder:

```
# reset ErrorDocument
ErrorDocument 404 default

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ item_processor.php [L]
```

Comment: Tried it, sadly, still redirected to our error page. I'm pretty sure there's redirects and pages that need to be ignored before it'll work, which is why I need a full "ignore previous htaccess redirects" option.

Comment: What is URL you entered and what error you got? Any .htaccess with `RewriteEngine On` by default overrides all other rewrite rules in parent .htaccess files

Comment: Just still getting our custom "page not found" error that the previous dev made.. looks like a custom page, not a page triggered by error code but reached someway else. However, I can't tell, the previous htaccesses are more complex than I'm used to.

Comment: To investigate you will need to enable `rewrite log` and check it's output